# Bootstrap: Links in navbar receive active class too late in the scroll

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

I've set up a smoothscroll which works great, just had to adjust it by 80px because my navbar is fixed at the top.

```
$('#navbar').find('a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 80
        }, 750);
    });
```

But I can't figure out how I can do the same adjustment for Bootstrap's active class on the links. They only receive the class once the anchored section is at the top of the browser screen, but my navbar is overlapping.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-nav a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        var targetOffset = $(target).offset().top - 80;
      
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: targetOffset
        }, 750);
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get windows scroll top offset and add your 80px. You can add the section padding or margin if you like.
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + 80;

    // Assign active class to nav links while scolling
    // (index) will return how many sections you have
    // Replace (section) with your sections class
    $('section').each(function(index) {         
        // Check offset
        if ( $(this).offset().top <= windowScroll ) {
            $('.navbar-nav a.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.navbar-nav a').eq(index).addClass('active');
        }
    });

}).scroll();
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin-top: 100px
}
section {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">section1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">section2</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">section3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">section4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section5">section5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container wrap">
    <section id="section1" class="jumbotron">
        <h4>Section 1</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>               
    </section>
    
    <section id="section2" class="jumbotron">
        <h4>Section 2</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p> 
    </section>
    <section id="section3" class="jumbotron">
        <h4>Section 3</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>  
    </section>
    <section id="section4" class="jumbotron">
        <h4>Section 4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="section5" class="jumbotron">
        <h4>Section 5</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>   
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this doesn't seem to work for me either. I've now changed my tactic and just added a bigger padding on the sections (and removed the 80px adjustment in the JS)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my tactic and just added a bigger padding on the sections (and removed the 80px adjustment in the JS), so the overlapping navbar is overlapping on the 80px padding instead. Not exactly what I wanted but it works.

If someone does have a solution to how I previously wanted it to work, I'd be interested in knowing the answer!

Thanks